# How do I remove files from an Eclipse Workspace?

Tags: eclipse

I want to remove files from an Eclipse workspace without deleting them. How can I do this?

The workspace has all the files in several directories.  So I want it to have all the files in a directory except several of them.

Comment: Remove from where? From a source folder? If so, why? From another folder? If so, why is folder in workspace? Please edit question to clarify what you want to remove, since only folders that where added to a project will show, so if you don't want the folder, remove it from the project.

Comment: Are you looking for [Resource filters](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fresourcefilters.htm)?

Comment: Probably. Under File - Properties, I have Resource, but no Resource filters.  Eclipse 4.6.0.

Now if I open PHP Explorer and use properties - I see resource filters.

Comment: Right-click folder in Package Explorer, and select "Properties", then expand "Resource" node, and select the "Resource Filters" node.

Comment: Now the problem is that I use remove filter for "createkml*", Exclude all, and Apply.

But the files still show up in PHP Explorer as being part of the project (and thus the workspace).

Comment: Hmm - I cannot find Package Explorer as I'm in PHP mode so it doesn't show up by default (and I tried searching for it). 

Can I use PHP Explorer or PHP Project Outline?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137706/discussion-between-aaron-kreider-and-andreas).